# How To Sandbox Individual Applications On OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, firefox, sandbox

I am trying to Sandbox Firefox on OS X.  I know on Linux, you have AppArmor.  On Windows, you Sandboxie.  Is there something built into OS X that will allow me to Sandbox individual applications?

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "sandbox"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Apple included a [sandbox facility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH1-SW1) with the release of Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard in 2006. This facility includes [sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man7/sandbox.7.html), [sandboxd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man8/sandboxd.8.html), [sandbox_init](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/sandbox_init.3.html), and [sandbox-exec](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sandbox-exec.1.html).

Comment: This answer is outdate and so are the links. Please update and try to include newer versions of Mac OS.

Comment: @DanRan lmao what is he supposed to do write an answer that matches documentation from 2018?